# Expanding nested JSON into multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following JSON response. I can normalize that data to get a dataframe.  The attributes column is nested and I cannot figure out how to expand it.

Here's my response:

```
response = {'data':     {'users': [ {'id': 12345, 'code': 'username1', 'attributes': []},
                                    {'id': 1460, 'code': 'username2', 'attributes': [{'id': 5, 'code': 'PD'}]}
                                 ]
                        }
            }
```

I'm trying to get to this:

```
   id     code           attributes.id             attributes.code 
0  12345  username1      None                      None
1  1460   username2      5                 PD
```

`stuff = pd.json_normalize(response['data'], record_path=['users'])` gets me here:

```
   id     code           attributes 
0  12345  username1      []
1  1460   username2      [{'id': 5, 'code': 'PD'}]
```

The brackets around the attributes values seem to be the issue, but I can't get rid of them no matter what I try.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with `drop=True` in [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) fr avod duplicated indices, then remove missing values for use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), rename columns names with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), last append to original DataFrame:

```
df = stuff.explode('attributes').reset_index(drop=True)

s = df.pop('attributes').dropna()
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(s).set_index(s.index).add_prefix('attributes.'))
print (df)
      id       code  attributes.id attributes.code
0  12345  username1            NaN             NaN
1   1460  username2            5.0              PD
```